# Can't upload pictures to Wordpress - issue with permissions (user became www-data)

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-20.04

I have an issue with wordpress. I can no longer see or upload any pictures on Wordpress. I'm running docker with nginx, mysql and php.

At the start of the project I saw all picture and could do anything with them but now I can't. For some reason if I upload a picture in wordpress I get that the user doing it is www-data. Pictures I uploaded 10 days ago were under my own user (lets say mike).

So, I went into my wp-uploads and saw that now every picture I upload is uploaded by www-data and not mike.

Does anyone know how to reverse this back to original setup?

Example:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mike mike 167490 feb 2 22:41 picture-one.png*

-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 153167 feb 5 12:53 picture-two.png
```

Comment: Have you taken back-ups?

Comment: I did but I'm trying to understand the issue. The backup works fine.